# How to pretty print the tooltip suggestions in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tooltip, pylance, pyright

I've tried to find a way to pretty print the tooltip suggestions I get for lists and dictionaries, but I'm not getting anywhere with this. At first I thought this content was provided by the language server, but now I'm not sure about this anymore. When I use Pylance, the tooltip popup doesn't suggest any list content at all, but when I use Pyright or Jedi, this content (list) is suggested.

I've tried pretty much all of the available settings in Pylance and Pyright, but there doesn't seem to be a way to change this behavior or alter it. I also played around with the editor settings, as the editor settings also has some parameters for the tooltip popup, but I couldn't find anything useful there either.

This is the tooltip result with Pylance enabled:
[image: This is the tooltip result with Pylance enabled]

This is the tooltip result with Pyright enabled:
[image: This is the tooltip result with Pyright enabled]

Upon closer inspection I noticed that the squiggly error line under "question_data" is the string that makes the tooltip suggestion popup, and Pyright nor Pylance are in the tooltip popup:

[image: tooltip result]

It already makes me wonder why they don't behave the same, as Pylance is built on Pyright, but that's another question. I don't think the language server has anything to do with this but correct me if I'm wrong.

I'd like to know if there's a way to change the way suggestions in the tooltip popup are displayed, so I can pretty print a list in the tooltip popup.